Secure folder debugging on Samsung, Android v. 14
I am trying to unbloat my Galaxy phone from preinstalled apps that cannot be uninstalled via regular means. The adb shell works perfectly, though not for Secure folder.
To clarify, I want to uninstall Chrome from within the Secure Folder, not the folder itself. Getting rid of Chrome from within 'regular user' worked as a charm but Secure folder cannot be accessed this way.
The command I used in the shell was pm uninstall --user 150 com.android.chrome

If the adb shell is not the way, how should I proceed? Is that even possible?
Thanks in advance for any help.
As I mentioned I went via wireless debugging and used the command:
pm uninstall --user 150 com.android.chrome
Simple button 'uninstall' is unavailable.

Why do you try to uninstall chrome when you want to uninstall Secure Folder? BTW please do not post text error message s as screenshot. In this case just including the error message as text without stack trace would be sufficient.

Hi. I do not want to  uninstall Secure Folder, I want to uninstall chrome from the SS
